# I want to add addtional files to existing archives (ZIP / RAR) or have the files added when compressing

Tags: zip, addition, archive, rar

I know how to do this for one archive at a time, but I want to add files, to multiple archives, in the same folder, simultaneously; if that is possible. I understand that I can do this with a batch file... but I don't know how to write the script / text.

So... I have several zip files in one folder. I want to add a specific text file and a specific image file to each/all of those zips. I don't want any other modifications of the zip files.

Or... is there a way to set WinRAR so that specific files will be automatically added whenever an archive is created?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('cal.zip', mode='a', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
z.write('/your/file/path') # or, z.writestr('your-filename', 'file-content')
z.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am completely ignorant about coding. Is this text for a batch file?

Comment: @Dan, sorry, this is a python scripts.